# js-mcrypt and php's mcrypt are not outputting the same values

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I need to encrypt data using AES in JavaScript and then send it to our server for PHP to decrypt. Yes, I know, this is not secure and people will be able to decrypt it - we're using this as a way to make it harder for people to reverse and deobfuscate our code.

I'm using this library:

https://github.com/Dexus/js-mcrypt/blob/master/mcrypt.js

I'm using Rijndael-128 and cbc for AES, with a block size of 16. I've verified that this value is the same for PHP & JS. I can encrypt and decrypt a string using the same key, IV, and rijndael-128/cbc in either JS and PHP, but for some reason PHP can't decrypt the output from JS. Can someone please help me out and point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Serpent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rijndael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mcrypt.js"></script>

<?php
    function hex2bin($text)
    {
        return pack('H*', $text);
    }

    echo mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    echo "->" . mcrypt_get_key_size('rijndael-128', 'cbc');

    $ciphertext_hex = "86B83EB77A6D40CACABAD79F0EA335E8454B1A9974B2D89D43B3EE0E25B649FB19EB88DF7A4490F9AB05F44701F081DD";
    $ciphertext = hex2bin($ciphertext_hex);

    $key_hex = "31323334353637383930313233343536";
    $key = hex2bin($key_hex);

    $iv = "1234567890123456";
    $cipher = "rijndael-128";
    $mode = "cbc";

    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt($cipher, $key, $ciphertext, $mode, $iv);

    echo "<h2>Enc in JS, Dec in PHP</h2>Encrypted: $ciphertext<br /><br />\n\nDecrypted: $plaintext";

    echo "<h2>Enc/Dec in PHP</h2>Encrypted: " . ($encd = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, "this is the message I want to encode", $mode, $iv)) . "<br><br>\n\n";
    echo "Decrypted: " . mcrypt_decrypt($cipher, $key, $encd, $mode, $iv);
?>

<div id='js_results'></div>
<script>
    var hexdigits='0123456789ABCDEF';
    var hexLookup=Array(256);
    for(var i=0;i<256;i++)
        hexLookup[i]=hexdigits.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(i));

    var bin2hex=function(str){
        var out='';
        for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
            out+=hexdigits[str.charCodeAt(i)>>4]+hexdigits[str.charCodeAt(i)&15];
        return out;
    }

    var hex2bin=function(str){
        var out='';
        var part=-1;
        for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            var t=hexLookup[str.charCodeAt(i)]
            if(t>-1){
                if(part>-1){
                    out+=String.fromCharCode(part|t);
                    part=-1;
                }else
                    part=t<<4;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    var cipher = "<?php echo $cipher; ?>";
    var mode = "<?php echo $mode; ?>";
    var key = hex2bin("<?php echo $key_hex; ?>");
    var iv = "<?php echo $iv; ?>";
    var msg = "this is the message I want to encode";

    var enc = mcrypt.Encrypt(msg, iv, key, cipher, mode);
    var enc_hex = bin2hex(enc);

    var enc_hex_static = "<?php echo $ciphertext_hex; ?>";
    var enc_static = hex2bin(enc_hex_static);
    var dec = mcrypt.Decrypt(enc_static, iv);

    document.getElementById('js_results').innerHTML = "<h2>Enc in JS</h2>Encrypted: " + enc + "<br><br>\n\nEnc in Hex: " + enc_hex + "<br><br>\n\nDec: " + dec;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both strings to use the same character encoding like utf8

Comment: You mean the encrypted strings?

Comment: The plain-text strings

Comment: Converting the javascript string to be encoded to utf8, and the decoded output in PHP to utf8, didn't fix the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution is to fix why quite early your encoding goes wrong. eg: the string after hex2bin on ciphertext, compared against js/php. I used different functions to test the output ( different implementations of hex2bin ) but i cannot pinpoint an error at a specific location other than your actual ciphertext is different between js/php. Ill try to find some time to figure out how to fix this.